# Missing values in dropdown

Tags: grid, drop-down-menu, janus

I have encountered a problem using a janus grid. I have created a dropdown and bound a datasource to it. The datasource is filled with data, but when I use the dropdown it doesn't show any values. I can choose one of the hidden values and the cell text is updated fine. It looks like the values are there but for some reason I can't see it. I have already checked the font properties.

What might be causing this?

Comment: So you are saying there are items in the list, but they don't have any text (ie they are blank)? If so, then ensure that you are setting the textMember of the dropdown list to a property that has values.